# <Error>: CGDataConsumer(url_close): write failed: -15

Tags: cocoa

```
<Error>: CGDataConsumer(url_close): write failed: -15.
<Error>: CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: failed with error code -15.
```

Does anybody know what could trigger this Errors and what they mean?

Answer (score 7):

I have seen this before when using an incorrectly defined URL. For example:

```
NSString *f = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.txt"];

// This is an invalid file url and will fail when you try to save to it.
NSURL *invalidFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:f];

// This URL is acceptable.
NSURL *validFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:f isDirectory:NO];
```